# Check multiple arrays for zero sum subquence

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, checksum

I would like to check multiple arrays if their sum is equal to zero and if yes, output yes. But only the first array is being read by the code.

There should be 3 outputs of (true or false) but I'm getting only 1 output instead

```
const arr0 = [3];
const arr1 = [4];
const arr2 = [2, 8, -9, 1];    

const arr = [arr0, arr1, arr2];

const zeroSum = arr => {
   const map = new Map();
   let sum = 0;
   for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      sum += arr[i];
      if(sum === 0 || map.get(sum)){
         return true;
      };
      map.set(sum, i);
   };
   return false;
};
console.log(zeroSum(arr));
```

Comment: Do you want the sum of the arrays merged together, or just the sum of each independent array?

Comment: sum of each independent array only @Andy

Comment: The key line is `sum += arr[i]`. `arr[i]` is an array and you're trying to add it to 0. You need to loop over the elements of `arr[i]` and add those to sum which would need to be declared for each outer loop.

Comment: @Andy Thank you, I'm still learning array. As of now I still didn't get it. But I'll take note of your comment

Answer (score 1):

1. As I mentioned in my comment `arr[i]` will always be an array. Trying to add that to `sum` will result in a string. You'll never get the result you want. To sum the elements of each array you need an inner loop to go over each element and add *those* to `sum` instead.
2. Currently you're only returning one thing: `true` or `false`. It sounds like you want an array into which you add the results of each sum, and then you can return that.
3. Not sure what you're using `Map` for so I've removed it from my example.

```js
const arr0 = [3];
const arr1 = [4];
const arr2 = [0];
const arr3 = [2, 8, -9, 1];    

const arr = [arr0, arr1, arr2, arr3];

function zeroSum(arr) {

  // Create an output array
  const out = [];

  // Loop over the arrays
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    // Reset the sum for each iteration
    let sum = 0;
    const inner = arr[i];

    // Loop over the elements of each array
    for (let j = 0; j < inner.length; j++) {

     // Add the elements to `sum`
     sum += inner[j];
    }

    // Push either true or false to
    // the output array depending on the
    // result of the condition
    if (sum === 0) {
      out.push(true);
    } else {
      out.push(false);
    }
  }

  // Finally return the array
  return out;
}

console.log(zeroSum(arr));
```